# NoSQL MongoDB vs GT.M

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

I have checked GT.M NoSQL database and seems it is recommended for bank systems. And found in some articles they said that MongoDB isn't suitable for transactions. Any more clarifications and differences?

Comment: nosql databases generally can't guarantee relational integrity. at best they have "eventually consistent", which is entirely unsuitable for a banking environment.

Comment: Care to share the articles about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MongoDB you do not have the notion of a transaction as it is for a RDBMS.

In MongoDB you have *Atomic Updates*. So if you are changing three documents in a unit of work and one of them fails to perform an update action the others are not rolled back as it is the case in an RDBMS.

In an RDBMS the system takes care, that it is left in a consistent state. And for some usage scenarios this is not needed and can limit your needed flexibility.

Answer (score 3):

GT.M is used in many banking systems, and also in healthcare applications. It is a high performance tool that doesn't do "sharding" as some NoSQL systems do, but rather provides "replication" so multiple computers can work with the same database, but also provide inter process communication using the shared database.  As has been mentioned before, a transaction based system will guarantee the grouping of several updates so that the database as a whole maintains consistency.

GT.M allows for multiple levels of replication, i.e. the original database may replicate to other machines, which themselves replicate to yet more machines.  This provides a high degree of redundancy and reliability.